# Google map API, directionService.route display different address in turn by turn list

Tags: google-maps

When render turn-by-turn list from the DirectionService. The list display different address from the input. Let say enter '1659 N Hobart Blvd Los Angeles, CA 90027' as origin then the directionService.route display the address as '1647 N Hobart Blvd, Los Angeles, CA 90027, USA' even the search result return 'ROOFTOP'. This also occurred in the destination address too.

How to make the direction result display the input addresses both origin and destination.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>4SoftPOS Directions</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
        }

        #map_canvas {
            height: 100%;
            width: 70%;
            float: right;
        }

        #direction_panel {
            height: 100%;
            overflow: scroll;
            background: aqua;
        }

        #control {
            background: #fff;
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 14px;
            font-family: Arial;
            border: 1px solid #ccc;
            box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);
            display: none;
        }

        #floating-panel {
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 25%;
            z-index: 5;
            background-color: #fff;
            padding: 5px;
            border: 1px solid #999;
            text-align: center;
            font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
            line-height: 30px;
            padding-left: 10px;
        }


        @media print {
            #map-canvas {
                width: 100%;
                margin: 0;
            }

            #direction_panel {
                width: 100%;
                position: static;
            }
        }

        .adp-placemark {
            background-color: #1C7DD7;
        }


        .adp-legal {
            color: black;
        }

        .warnbox-content {
            background: white;
            color: black;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"
            src='http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js'></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

        // register when errors suppress them
        window.onerror = function () {
            // Return true to tell IE we handled it
            return true;
        };

        var geocoder;
        var map;
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService;
        var origin = '1659 N Hobart Blvd Los Angeles, CA 90027';
        var destination = '7352 Camellia Ave N Holloywood, CA 91605';
        var latlng_origin;
        var latlng_destination;
        var markers = [];

        //var origin = new google.maps.LatLng([origin]);
        //var destination = new google.maps.LatLng([destination]);
        function isBlank(str) {
            return (!str || /^\s*$/.test(str));
        }

        function isEmpty(str) {
            return (!str || 0 === str.length);
        }

        function initialize() {
            // init direction services
            directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
            if (isBlank(destination) || isEmpty(destination)) {
                alert("Destination is not spedified.");
                displayDefault();
            } else {
                displayDirection();
            }
        }

        function displayDefault() {
            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': origin }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    latlng_origin = results[0].geometry.location;
                    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'),
                    {
                        zoom: 18,
                        center: latlng_origin
                    });
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: latlng_origin,
                        map: map,
                        title: 'Your restaurant'
                    });

                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: origin " + status);
                }
            });
        }

        function displayDirection() {
            // init google map and display the map at map_canvas
            var myOptions = {
                zoom: 1,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
                center: origin
            }
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

            // set display to show traffic
            var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
            trafficLayer.setMap(map);

            // init direction display
            directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
            // set display direction turn by turn
            directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
            // display direction panel
            directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("turnbyturn"));

            geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': origin }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == window.google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    latlng_origin = results[0].geometry.location;
                    var final_result;
                    var i = 0;
                    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) alert(results[i].geometry.location_type); // for debug

                    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
                        if (results[i].geometry.location_type === google.maps.GeocoderLocationType.ROOFTOP) final_result = results[i];
                    if (typeof final_result === "undefined")
                        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
                            if (results[i].geometry.location_type === google.maps.GeocoderLocationType.RANGE_INTERPOLATED) final_result = results[i];
                    if (typeof final_result === "undefined")
                        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
                            if (results[i].geometry.location_type === google.maps.GeocoderLocationType.GEOMETRIC_CENTER) final_result = results[i];
                    if (typeof final_result === "undefined")
                        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
                            if (results[i].geometry.location_type === google.maps.GeocoderLocationType.APPROXIMATE) final_result = results[i];

                    if (typeof final_result !== "undefined") latlng_origin = final_result.geometry.location;
                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: origin " + status);
                }
                if (latlng_origin && latlng_destination) calcRoute();
            });

            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': destination }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    latlng_destination = results[0].geometry.location;
                    var final_result;
                    var i = 0;
                    //for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++) alert(results[i].geometry.location_type); // for debug

                    for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
                        if (results[i].geometry.location_type === google.maps.GeocoderLocationType.ROOFTOP) final_result = results[i];
                    if (typeof final_result === "undefined")
                        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
                            if (results[i].geometry.location_type === google.maps.GeocoderLocationType.RANGE_INTERPOLATED) final_result = results[i];
                    if (typeof final_result === "undefined")
                        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
                            if (results[i].geometry.location_type === google.maps.GeocoderLocationType.GEOMETRIC_CENTER) final_result = results[i];
                    if (typeof final_result === "undefined")
                        for (i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
                            if (results[i].geometry.location_type === google.maps.GeocoderLocationType.APPROXIMATE) final_result = results[i];

                    if (typeof final_result !== "undefined") latlng_destination = final_result.geometry.location;
                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: destination " + status);
                }
                if (latlng_origin && latlng_destination) calcRoute();
            });
        }

        function calcRoute() {
            var selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value;
            var request = {
                origin: latlng_origin,
                destination: latlng_destination,
                // Note that Javascript allows us to access the constant
                // using square brackets and a string value as its
                // "property."
                travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
            };
            directionsService.route(request, function (response, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                    directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
                }
            });
        }

        function codeAddress() {
            var address = document.getElementById("address").value;
            geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function (results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        map: map,
                        position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });
                } else {
                    alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                }
            });

            var image = 'down2.png';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: origin,
                map: map,
                icon: image,
                animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                title: "Click for show the data of the client"
            });
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="initialize()">
    <div id="map_canvas"></div>
    <div id="direction_panel">
        <strong>Mode of Travel: </strong>
        <select id="mode" onchange="calcRoute();">
            <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
            <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
            <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
        </select>
        <div id="turnbyturn"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you pass the origin and destination addresses directly in to the directions service rather than geocoding the first and passing in the resulting google. maps.LatLng, the address will be the same.

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/7bc54bzx/5/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;
var directionsDisplay;
var directionsService;
var origin = '1659 N Hobart Blvd Los Angeles, CA 90027';
var destination = '7352 Camellia Ave N Holloywood, CA 91605';
var latlng_origin;
var latlng_destination;
var markers = [];

function initialize() {
  // init direction services
  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  displayDirection();
}

function displayDirection() {
  // init google map and display the map at map_canvas
  var myOptions = {
    zoom: 1,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
    // center: origin
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

  // set display to show traffic
  var trafficLayer = new google.maps.TrafficLayer();
  trafficLayer.setMap(map);

  // init direction display
  directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
  // set display direction turn by turn
  directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
  // display direction panel
  directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById("turnbyturn"));
  calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {
  var selectedMode = document.getElementById("mode").value;
  var request = {
    origin: origin, // latlng_origin,
    destination: destination, // latlng_destination,
    // Note that Javascript allows us to access the constant
    // using square brackets and a string value as its
    // "property."
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode[selectedMode]
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', function() {
  initialize();
  displayDirection();
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
#map_canvas {
  height: 350px;
  width: 70%;
  /* float: right;*/
}
#direction_panel {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  background: aqua;
}
#control {
  background: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: Arial;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);
  display: none;
}
#floating-panel {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 25%;
  z-index: 5;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #999;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: 'Roboto', 'sans-serif';
  line-height: 30px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
@media print {
  #map-canvas {
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
  }
  #direction_panel {
    width: 100%;
    position: static;
  }
}
.adp-placemark {
  background-color: #1C7DD7;
}
.adp-legal {
  color: black;
}
.warnbox-content {
  background: white;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<script src="https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markerclusterer/src/markerclusterer.js"></script>
<div id="floating-panel">
  <b>Mode of Travel: </b>
  <select id="mode">
    <option value="DRIVING">Driving</option>
    <option value="WALKING">Walking</option>
    <option value="BICYCLING">Bicycling</option>
    <option value="TRANSIT">Transit</option>
  </select>
</div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
<div id="turnbyturn"></div>
```